# Sql: To fetch all record along with matching record

Tags: mysql, sql

Fiddle i created: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e22eb6/2

[image: Table Relation ship]

Data for each tables

[image: userdetails]

[image: authority_master]

[image: users_authority_relation]

I tried below query but its only showing result which particular user has authority/permission assigned on him, i want  all records(permission avaialble) in `authority_master` table along with matched one.

```sql
SELECT U.first_name, 
       UR.authority_id as AUTHORITY_REL_AUTH_ID,
       AM.authority 
FROM userdetails U 
INNER JOIN users_authority_relation UR 
       ON U.user_id=UR.user_id 
LEFT JOIN authority_master AM 
       ON AM.authority_id=UR.authority_id 
WHERE U.user_id=1;
```

```
 first_name   AUTHORITY_REL_AUTH_ID authority 
 admin                         1    ADMIN_USER
 admin                         2    STANDARD_USER
 admin                         4    HR_PERMISSION`
```

**Expected output**(order does not matter), how to get this output?

```
first_name   AUTHORITY_REL_AUTH_ID  authority
 admin                         1    ADMIN_USER
 admin                         2    STANDARD_USER 
admin                         null  NEW_CANDIDATE
 admin                         4    HR_PERMISSION
```

Comment: Try changing that INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @O.Jones I tried but still the same result only matched record its showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't pretty, but you need the hole thing

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COALESCE(U.first_name,U2.first_name)

       ,UR.authority_id as AUTHORITY_REL_AUTH_ID,
       AM.authority 
FROM ( userdetails U
INNER JOIN users_authority_relation UR 
       ON U.user_id=UR.user_id  ANd u.user_id = 1)
RIGHT JOIN (userdetails U2 CROSS JOIN authority_master AM )
       ON AM.authority_id=UR.authority_id
WHERE U2.user_id = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e22eb6/49/0)**:

```
| COALESCE(U.first_name,U2.first_name) | AUTHORITY_REL_AUTH_ID |     authority |
|--------------------------------------|-----------------------|---------------|
|                                admin |                     1 |    ADMIN_USER |
|                                admin |                     2 | STANDARD_USER |
|                                admin |                (null) | NEW_CANDIDATE |
|                                admin |                     4 | HR_PERMISSION |
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
SELECT U.first_name, UR.authority_id as AUTHORITY_REL_AUTH_ID, AM.authority 
FROM authority_master AM
LEFT JOIN users_authority_relation UR ON AM.authority_id=UR.authority_id AND UR.user_id = 1
LEFT JOIN userdetails U ON U.user_id = 1
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e22eb6/67)

Comment: This is not my expection result. I want list by userId, In result i want all the result from `authority_master` even if it does not available in users_authority_relation

Comment: I have made an update